# Geometric series; Bernoulli Random Variable

Tags: probability, probability-theory, proof-verification

I am trying to check whether something is a valid probability mass function.

> Let $m = \frac{1}{2}$ and $n = \frac{1}{2}$ be the probabilities of
>   success and       failure respectively and let $p(k)$ be a probability
>   mass function such that
>
> $$p(k) = m\sum_{i = 1}^k n^i + n\sum_{i=1}^k m^i.$$

Is this a valid probability mass function?

Say we carry out this test infinitely many times, does $p(k) = 1$?

We recognise that the probability mass function is a sum of two slightly shifted geometric series. Let's consider one of the two (the other will follow the exact same argument).

Say we are summing from $0$ to $\infty$, that is let

$$S_0 = \sum_{i=0}^{\infty}n^i.$$

Then this is simply evaluated as

$$S_0 = 1 + n + n^2 + n^3 + \cdots = \frac{1}{1-n}$$

which is perfectly valid as $n = \frac{1}{2}$. If, then, I start this sequence at $i = 1$, is it valid to say that

$$S_1 = \sum_{i=1}^\infty n^i= \frac{1}{1-n} - 1 = \frac{1 - (1-n)}{1-n} = \frac{n}{1-n}$$

and as such that, as $k \to \infty$, we have something like

$$\frac{mn}{1-n} + \frac{mn}{1-m} = 1.$$

Have I made any ridiculous logical jumps or is this valid? Thanks for any advice.

Comment: $p(1)=1/2$, $p(2)=3/4$. These already add up to more than $1$. Not a mass fumction. It will be OK if we let $\Pr(X\le k)$ be given by your sum.

Comment: Have just re-read the notes I was given and now feel like a plonker for spending so much time asking this question. Does your edit suggest that this might be valid for a CDF?

Comment: Technically a cdf is defined for all real $x$. But your expression is in spirit fairly close to a cdf.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using your formula we obtain $p(1)=\frac{1}{2}$ and $p(2)=\frac{3}{4}$. Thus $p(1)+p(2)\gt 1$, which is impossible.

If we define the distribution of a random variable $X$ by saying that $\Pr(X\le k)$ is given by your sum, then we will have defined a legitimate distribution. The probability mass function is then given by $p(k)=mn^k+nm^k$. Since $m=n=\frac{1}{2}$, it would be clearer to say $p(k)=\frac{1}{2^k}$ for every positive integer $k$.

Comment: Just to ask a further question quickly, if I were to imagine this as, say, flipping a coin $k$ times until I have at least one head and one tail, would $$p(k) = mn^k + nm^k$$

be a valid p.m.f. for this? I'm fairly new to probability!

Comment: Let us solve that problem, using a fair coin though it quickly generalizes to unfair coins. Let random variable $X$ be the number of tosses. This number is $\ge 2$. We have $X=k$ if we get $k-1$ heads and then a tail, or the other way around. The probability is $\frac{1}{2^{k-1}}\cdot \frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2^{k-1}}\cdot \frac{1}{2}$, which is $\frac{1}{2^{k-1}}$ for $k\ge 2$.